# API calls from xPage

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpinc, hcl-notes

I have an xPage that uses an Server side Javascript beforePageLoad call to populate some fields from a remote JSON REST service.

Get this error .....
Error calling method 'openConnection()' on java class 'java.net.URL'
ECL Permission Denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.net.www.protocol.https")

This works in a web browser. Are there any client settings I need to change or is there a better way to do this so I can also use it in the Notes XPiNC environment?

Code is below ... thanks in advance

```
var url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/" + CompanyNo;

var url:java.net.URL = new java.net.URL(url);
var urlconn:java.net.URLConnection = url.openConnection();
urlconn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxx==");
if (urlconn.getResponseCode() < 400) {
 var reader:java.io.BufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(
                                            new java.io.InputStreamReader(
                                            urlconn.getInputStream())
                                        );
 var inputLine;
    var jsonTxt = "";
    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
        jsonTxt += inputLine;
    }
    reader.close();

    viewScope.Response = fromJson(jsonTxt);
} else {
       /* error from server */

    viewScope.Response = "Error " + urlconn.getResponseCode() + url;
    }
```

Comment: Short answer: Don't do this in JavaScript, long answer: see below

Comment: I agree with @stwissel.  But you could possibly append to domino\jvm\lib\java.policy "grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };  "  -- does that clear the security error?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to change in this approach:

- Don't use the Java classes from SSJS. Wrap your whole logic into a Java bean. It gives you a better development experience and [is easier to test](https://www.wissel.net/blog/2013/06/managed-beans-xpages-and-testability.html)
- UrlConnection is way too low level, and is a headache for https. Use the [Apache HTTP client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library (which is AFAIK available on the Domino server)

Some [sample code](https://wissel.net/blog/2007/08/ssl-in-domino-agents.html) should get you started along these lines:

```java
 HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
 HttpMethod httpMethod = new GetMethod( this.targetURL );
 int statusCode = httpclient.executeMethod(httpMethod);
 // TODO Check for statusCode 200
 String result = httpMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

Also checkout this [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl)

Comment: thanks for the pointers - Sorry to be slow (I'am old school Notes developer thats not moved with the times!) 
Can you point me to a step by step demo of creating java beans  so I can learn this too :)

Comment: Sure. Here you go: https://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/creating-your-first-managed-bean-for-xpages.html

Comment: I've made a start at doing the java bean  - thanks for your help - the code seems to run on a local replica but not on the server - are there some permissions that need to be changed?

Comment: Had to make changes to Server security doc - added my ID (was in a group previously) and it started working :)

Comment: I've got my java bean working (at last) - BUT - the faces-config.xml appears to be overwritten (I assume by design task) - it is not being inherited from the template though .... any ideas?